# The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '' is not rooted

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am trying to upload the document on Shared location Server (application is on one server and document upload folder is on other server). while saving I am getting *"The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '' is not rooted"* error.

```
var folderPath = string.Empty;
var fileFullName = string.Empty;
var fullFilePath = string.Empty;

var dir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocPath"];

folderPath = Path.Combine(dir, "Sample");

fileFullName = attachmentEntites.Id + "_" + attachmentEntites.AttachmentId + attachmentEntites.FileExtn;

fullFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileFullName.ToString());

if (File.Exists(fullFilePath))
{
  File.Delete(fullFilePath);
}

fuFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(fullFilePath);

<add key="DocPath" value="\\Server2\UpDoc\" />
```

Comment: Try mapping the path to a drive letter.

Comment: In your code above the variable _fileFullName_ is empty when you Combine with the path part. Are you trying to save the file using a folder name? By the way, no need call to ToString on a string variable

Comment: @RacilHilan File is getting saved on local when using folderPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("UpDoc"), "Sample");

Comment: @Steve Sorry, I forgot to mention file name, I updated the question

Comment: *File is getting saved on local*, yes I understand that. I was suggesting to try mapping the network drive and then use the new path with drive letter to satisfy `SaveAs()`. I don't know your server version, but [here is how you do it on Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4026635/windows-map-a-network-drive).